# Can I have some attributes in my model without having these as database columns but map these instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

My use case is as follows:

I am reading a csv file and I want to get the column headers there as a hash.
Then Im saving the row-values of the these column names into a database.

What I want to do is:

- incoming CSV file hash-keys = `[Col1, Col2, Col3]`
- I want to map the values of these to the following database columns: `[colA, colB, colC]`
- I don't want my database columns to be named `Col1, Col2, Col3` but I want these as model attributes.

How do I make a model where some attributes are not database columns?

Thanks

Comment: `attr_accessor` not good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Write the database tables as Row ->* Field (`row.has_many fields`).

Then in your `Row` class override `method_missing`, and inside that look up the target field via the missing name. So if `Field.name` == `'foo'`, then `row.foo` will fetch this record and return its value. When you call `row.foo` = `'bar'`, that will pass `:'foo='` to `method_missing`; you can detect the `=` and assign a value to the target field. Googling for 'ActiveRecord method_missing has_many' might hit some code that already does this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do with each column name.

```
col = 'Col20'
```

To convert it to lowercase + letters format that you want, first get the number:

```
number = col.match(/(\d+)/).try(:[],1).to_i
=> "20"
```

The above will attempt to find a number and then if there's a match, it will try to get that number.

Then convert (1=A, 20=T, ...):

```
new_col = col.downcase.sub( /\d+/, (number+64).chr )
=> "colT"
```

Then define such a property on the object you want it on like this:

```
my_object.class_eval { attr_accessor new_col }
```

And assign a value like this:

```
my_object.colT = "New Value"
```

Or dynamically:

```
my_object.send "#{new_col}=", "New Value"
```

And get its existing value by calling it by name:

```
my_object.colT
=> "New Value"
```

Or dynamically:

```
my_object.send new_col
=> "New Value"
```